# Using Ping in Parallel in a Bash Script

Tags: bash, ping

So I'm trying to ping a range of addresses in parallel in a bash script, count the ones that are alive, and print them out. The script works to ping the addresses and print the live ones out but it always outputs:

"There were 0 online hosts and 254 offline hosts"

It's not incrementing the ALIVE variable in my code, maybe because it's in a subshell? How could I get around this? Here's what I have right now:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOTAL=0
ALIVE=0

if [ $# -eq 3 ]
then
    echo -n 'Live hosts:'
    for ((i = $2; i <= $3 && i <= 254; ++i))
    do
        ((++TOTAL))
        ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -w 1 -W 1 $1.$i > /dev/null && ((++ALIVE)) && echo "    $1.$i" &
    done

    echo "There were $ALIVE online hosts and $((($TOTAL - $ALIVE))) offline hosts"
else
    echo "USAGE: pingRange.sh <first 3 octets of ip> <last octet start> <last octet end>"
    echo "    Ex: pingRange.sh 192.168.0 1 254
```

Note: An example input for the script is shown in the "else" part.

Note 2: Yes I know nmap is easier, I've already wrote a working script with nmap, trying to do one for ping now.

Note 3: I used a temporary file and it worked, updated code has #NEW comment:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 3 ]
then
    TOTAL=0 #NEW
    TEMP=mktemp #NEW
    echo -n 'Live hosts:'
    for ((i = $2; i <= $3 && i <= 254; ++i))
    do
        ((++TOTAL))
        ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -w 1 -W 1 $1.$i > /dev/null && echo "    $1.$i" >> $TEMP & #NEW
    done
    wait #NEW
    cat $TEMP

    ALIVE=$(cat $TEMP | wc -l) #NEW
    echo "There were $ALIVE online hosts and $((($TOTAL - $ALIVE))) offline hosts"

    rm $TEMP #NEW
else
    echo "USAGE: pingRange.sh <first 3 octets of ip> <last octet start> <last octet end>"
    echo "    Ex: pingRange.sh 192.168.0 1 254
```

Comment: Would be nice to share nmap solution.

Comment: It's the subshell, yes. You can write to a file instead

Comment: Why not use `nmap` in your script? https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344360/collect-exit-codes-of-parallel-background-processes-sub-shells Simplest solution seems to be along lines of: `job1 & code1=$!; ...; wait $code1; ans=$?;`

Comment: `Note 3 .. it worked ..` - so you should post that as an answer to your question. In your script `TEMP=mktemp` `TEMP`is literallly the string `mktemp`, ie. `TEMP="mktemp"`. You want `TEMP=$(mktemp)` to execute `mktemp` command.

Comment: @KamilCuk I posted what I did after the note. The answer that I selected was more readable and also had a solution that didn't need to use a temporary file so I selected it as a better answer instead.

Comment: Read the man page. The solution is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... && ((++ALIVE)) && ... &
```

This expression is run inside inside another process, so the changes are not visible in your parent process

```
a=1
((++a)) &    # <- is run as another process
echo "$a"  # this will print 1 ...

(
    ((++a))
    echo "$a"
) &          # this will print 2 in the background

wait
```

So, we want to run `(( $3 - $2 ))` processes. Each of these processes will be run concurrently. We need to get output from all these processes on the end. We arrive at what we call "synchronization". We need to synchronize all values from all the processes to one point.
We can imagine using ex. 255 files, one file unique for each process. Then after childs execute we can query the files.
The easiest is to use stdout or other line-buffered stream:

```
live_hosts=$(
   for ((i = $2; i <= $3 && i <= 254; ++i)); do
       # `if` is more readable then `a && b`
       (
          if ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -w 1 -W 1 "$1.$i" >/dev/null; then
              echo "$1.$i"
          fi
       ) &
   done
   wait  # remember to wait for all the childs
)
```

Because stdout *should be* line buffered, the multiple `echo "$1.$i"` shouldn't intercept the write, so we should arrive at just a variable with lines. Then you can just:

```
echo "There were $(printf "$live_hosts" | wc -l) online hosts"
```

But we could do this with a temporary directory:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

for ((i = $2; i <= $3 && i <= 254; ++i)); do
   (
      if ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -w 1 -W 1 "$1.$i" >/dev/null; then
           # create a file with the name "$i" inside tmpdir
           # I don't think content matters (just the name of file)
           touch "$tmpdir"/"$i"
       fi 
    ) &
done
wait

# ex. the count of alives are the count of files inside out tmpdir
alive=$(find "$tmpdir" -type f -print . | wc -c)

# this is funny
for i in "$tmpdir"/*; do
      echo "$1.$i is alive!"
done

# remember to cleanup
rm -r "$tmpdir"
```

And just to make it interesting and because we love oneliners, here's a solution using `xargs` and `seq`:

```
live_hosts=$(seq -f "$1.%.0f" "$2" "$3" | xargs -n1 -P0 -- sh -c 'ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -w 1 -W 1 "$1" >/dev/null && echo "$1"' --)
alive=$(echo "$live_hosts" | wc -l)
# well, if just the count matters, add the `| wc -l` to the one liner ..
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite true; `&&` doesn't create subshell, `&` does.

Comment: Why not use `nmap -sn ...` instead of trying to write a script?

Comment: @RedCricket OP specifically said he did nmap and is interested in bash solution using ping.

Comment: @KamilCuk using `nmap -sn` is a ping.

Comment: @RedCricket Yes, I used `nmap -sn` in another implementation, this question was asking specifically about using the `ping` command.

Comment: Note that using output from `xargs -P` is not generally safe: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this just using `wait`.

Amending your code, something like (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

TOTAL=0
ALIVE=0

if [ $# -eq 3 ]
then
    unset pids
    declare -A pids
    echo -n 'Live hosts:'
    for ((i = $2; i <= $3 && i <= 254; ++i))
    do
        ((++TOTAL))
        ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -w 1 -W 1 $1.$i > /dev/null &
        pids[$i]=$!
    done

    for i in "${!pids[@]}"
    do
        wait ${pids[$i]} && ((++ALIVE)) && echo "    $1.$i"
    done

    echo "There were $ALIVE online hosts and $((($TOTAL - $ALIVE))) offline hosts"
else
    # ...
```

- `unset` / `declare` - just to be safe
- `ping ... &` still runs the comand in the background
- `pids[$i]=$!` saves its pid
- `for ...` loops over the keys
- `wait ${pids[$i]}` returns the exit status after cmd has completed
- `&& ...` does the same as before

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
pingrange() {
  three=$1
  start=$2
  end=$3
  total=$(($end-$start))
  online="$(seq $start $end |
    parallel -j0 "ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -w 1 -W 1 $three.{} > /dev/null && echo '    $three.{}'")"
  alive=$(echo "$online" | wc -l)
  offline=$((total-alive))
  echo "$online"
  echo "There were $alive online hosts and $offline offline hosts"
}
```

It runs correctly even if your system cannot run all `ping`s in parallel at the same time (e.g. if your process table is near full).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use :

```
fping -g $three.$start $three.$end
```

and work on the output. See *man [fping](https://fping.org/fping.1.html)* for further options.