# ping specified ip ranges to txt at one time (not one after one) - is it possible?

Tags: linux, bash, ping

I need to ping specified IP ranges like - from 192.168.1.**41** to 192.168.1.**50**. and export it to file.txt

I'm newbie and im trying to learn to 'programming' 
I have something like this:

```
file=something.txt
for IP in 192.168.1.{41..50}
do
echo "pinging ${IP}"
echo "PINGING ${IP} ">>${file}
ping -c 10 $IP >>${file}
done
```

But it pings one after one. Can I make ping at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Ping in Parallel in a Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988277/using-ping-in-parallel-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your code async :

```sh
for IP in 192.168.1.{41..50}
do
echo "pinging ${IP}" &
echo "PINGING ${IP} ">>${file} &
ping -c 10 $IP >>${file} &
done
```

If you are not satisfied you can also parallelize your code with xargs but i think it depends on the thread number so you will be limited:

```sh
for IP in 192.168.1.{41..50}
do
echo ${IP}
done | xargs -P 10 -n1  -I "ip_address" sh -c "ping -c 10 ip_address > ip_address.txt"
```

Comment: Second option is cool. But if one of them does not pinging I don't know which one.

Comment: i think the task is how to write everything into same file in right order

Comment: @GuiltySimpson Well, if you are OK with all logs are printed to different files then you can use updated script.

Comment: @Kerematam actually it does not work for me.
"ping: ip_address: Name or service not known"

Comment: are you sure you use ```-I "ip_address"``` flag; it should work like an template engine and replace the ip_address with given IP address. Also my xargs version (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git. I dont know if some of xargs clients dont have such options.

Comment: You are welcome, please accept my answer if this answer is what you wanted.